# Select closest element of certain type - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to select an element with some selector, and the select the closest `<p>` element to it (note that the p is not nested with the former element). How would I do that? I tried `closest()`, but that only works if the element is nested.

EDIT: a definition of closest:

```
<a id="myelement"></a>
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
```

In this case, `p#1` would be selected, assuming `#myelement` is the element in question.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: "closest" in what way? Could you provide an example html structure?

Comment: That would return me all of the `<p>`s. I just need the closest one.

Comment: closest parent? closest sibling? closest cousin? closest child?

Comment: @SaadImran.: not sure `nextUntil` would work. According to the docs: `Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.` That would not include the `<p>` element when specified as a selector.

Comment: It would work if combined with `.next()`, `.nextUntil("p").next()`

Answer (score 4):

Given your HTML is:

```
<a id="myelement"></a>
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
```

The reason [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) doesn't work is because:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing **up** through the DOM tree.

Use [**next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead if the 'p' tag will always be the next element:

```
$('#myelement').next();
```

However, if you could end up with any additional elements in-between the `a` and the first `p` tag than one of the ways to get it is to use [**nextAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

```
$('#myelement').nextAll('p').eq(0);
```

There is many other ways to get that `<p>` element for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in your case, but I believe `.next` would be the better choice if your data is always in the form you posted.

Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<a id="myelement">a</a>
<p id="1">1</p>
<p id="2">2</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myelement").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).next("p").attr("id"));
    console.log($(this).siblings("p")[0].id);
});​
```

You'll see that both of the above console logs report and id of `1`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tupdE/)**

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gpinto/PTFgG/1/

```
function findFirstParagraph() {

   var siblings = $('#myElement').siblings();

    siblings.each(function(index) {
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == 1) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });

}​
```

Comment: is this answer or question? Least you could do is verify that solution you're giving is correct.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle example, @Tom

Answer (score 0):

try using `next()` http://api.jquery.com/next/

as per the latest OP edit: jsfiddle.net/KXPwx/9

Comment: next() gets you the next element. check out this eg. http://jsfiddle.net/KXPwx/8/

Comment: does that answer your question? If so, please accept and rate my answer, helps me get some points :)

Answer (score 0):

You tried .next() or .prev().. Maybe use .eq(0)??

You can also use .parent() or .parents('.selector')

Answer (score 0):

try `.find()`

there are many functions that do similar things but for me, using something like `$(this).find( 'selector here' )` or `$(' id or class selector here').find('id/class here')` works wonders lol.

Good luck